# Can not start laravel after trying to install library

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, package

I have web-app on Laravel and I tried to update yajra/datatables to last version, so it needed

```
'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider'
```

I tried composer update, so it didn't help.
Now I removed this line from `composer.json`

But on calling  `php artisan clear-compiled`

It shows me an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/html/talimger.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 575

Show where I should remove this Maatwebsite files
`

Comment: Can you update your code to show exactly how that `'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider'` looks in the config file and also which config file you have put it in? I'm also unclear about which line you removed from composer.json? Also, did you run `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: yes I did composer dump-autoload, so also I remove all Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider from files.
May be its because yajra/datatables library use Maatwebsite\Excel?

Comment: You said that you "removed this line from `composer.json`" but I still don't understand which line you are talking about.

Comment: in require field I wrote before "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0", and I removed it

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer I posted and then comment on there if you have further problems.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions at https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel tell you what to do, but not how to do it. The assumption is that you already know a bit about composer.

Here's the 'how to do it'...

1) Remove the service provider entries you made and delete any lines you added to composer and then type the following:

`composer require "maatwebsite/excel"`

2) After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

**Laravel 5.1:**

`'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',`

**Laravel 5.2:**

`Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,`

3) You can use the facade for shorter code. Add this to your aliases:

**Laravel 5.1:**

`'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',`

**Laravel 5.2:**

`'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel,::class`

Answer (score 0):

Comment out 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' from the providers array in app.php under config then run composer update when you are done then your uncomment it.

Comment: I did it, but nothing changed